# Google spreadsheet importxml : how to grab all names of element nodes in XML

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets

I'm trying to use importxml function to import XML.

```
<item>
    <name>James</name>
    <date>11/11/2016</date>
    <description>Student</description>
</item>
```

If I use,

```
=importxml(URL, "//item")
```

I can import the information, but not the names of each information.

I'd like to pull something like this

```
name      date       description
James     11/11/2016 Student
```

Any xPath function to do this?

Comment: can you share the sample url so i can test really quick before posting? you should be able to just put "//item/name" but there sometimes can be little nuances to it

Comment: http://www.kobis.or.kr/kobisopenapi/webservice/rest/boxoffice/searchDailyBoxOfficeList.xml?key=430156241533f1d058c603178cc3ca0e&targetDt=20120101

Here I would pull data using "//dailyBoxOffice" but I'd like to pull names of each column which is quite many to copy/paste one by one. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: Do you mean the headers such as the ones nested under dailyBoxOffice? so that you can choose specific columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the headers with this formula:

```
=unique(arrayformula(regexreplace(transpose(split(IMPORTDATA(A1),"><",false)),">.*|\/","")))
```

Basically what I do, is use importdata to pull everything on the page, then using split and transpose functions, I force it to split based on each nested item `><` , transpose is to swap it vertically.

At that point this is what you would see:

[image]

Then using regexreplace with arrayformula I remove all the data after the headers with `">.*|\/"` and then use unique to give me a final unique list of all headers.

[image]

Comment: My import data have some commas that are not meant to be delimiters.  This breaks ```IMPORTDATA```.  Is there a way to accomplish the same as the above solution with my data using ```IMPORTDATA``` such as using ```SUBSTITUTE``` or ```REGEXREPLACE``` or another function to replace the commas?

Comment: @Catalyx Yes - i recommend you wrap your import function with `=concatenate(importdata(your_url))`  to combine it all into one cell instead. or if you really prefer to replace the commas`regexreplace(data, "[,]", "")`