# How to Import All Element Nodes in Google Sheets from XML

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

**Is there a way to download a full XML schema including headers into a Google Sheet worksheet?**

I'm looking to import all elements including the headers from an online XML page into Google Sheets.

The XML page looks like this:

```
<staff>
    <admin>
        <first-name>Patrice</first-name>
        <family-name>Withers</family-name>
        <year-started>2006</year-started>
        <starting-salary>30,500</starting-salary>
        <current-salary>34,000</current-salary>
    </admin>
    <admin>
        <first-name>Shelly</first-name>
        <family-name>Lancer</family-name>
        <year-started>2015</year-started>
        <starting-salary>32,500</starting-salary>
        <current-salary>33,500</current-salary>
    </admin>
</staff>
<students>
    <full-time>
        <first-name>Henry</first-name>
        <family-name>Nunes</family-name>
        <status>Freshman</status>
        <current-tuition>2,400</current-tuition>
        <last-year-tuition>2,200</last-year-tuition>
    </full-time>
    <part-time>
        <first-name>Leslie</first-name>
        <family-name>Franks</family-name>
        <status>Senior</status>
        <current-tuition>2,300</current-tuition>
        <last-year-tuition>2,100</last-year-tuition>
    </part-time>
</students>
```

I'm trying to have Google Sheets download the full XML page, including the element headers, and display it, preferably as above in indented columns, or in a single column to look like this:

```
<staff>
<admin>
<first-name>Patrice</first-name>
<family-name>Withers</family-name>
<year-started>2006</year-started>
<starting-salary>30,500</starting-salary>
<current-salary>34,000</current-salary>
</admin>
<admin>
<first-name>Shelly</first-name>
<family-name>Lancer</family-name>
<year-started>2015</year-started>
<starting-salary>32,500</starting-salary>
<current-salary>33,500</current-salary>
</admin>
</staff>
<students>
<full-time>
<first-name>Henry</first-name>
<family-name>Nunes</family-name>
<status>Freshman</status>
<current-tuition>2,400</current-tuition>
<last-year-tuition>2,200</last-year-tuition>
</full-time>
<part-time>
<first-name>Leslie</first-name>
<family-name>Franks</family-name>
<status>Senior</status>
<current-tuition>2,300</current-tuition>
<last-year-tuition>2,100</last-year-tuition>
</students>
```

`IMPORTDATA`, as another user was advised with a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40562451/google-spreadsheet-importxml-how-to-grab-all-names-of-element-nodes-in-xml), failed because some of the XML data have commas, similar to the sample output above.

Comment: whats the url??

Comment: @player0 The XML page output unfortunately requires authentication credentials.  Is there any specific info from the output that would help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the url of yours can be **scraped** from behind authentication credentials you could try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA("url_here"), 5000, 20)),,999^99))))
```

also you could perhaps try:

```
=IMPORTXML("url_here", "//*")
```

Comment: the latter displays the entire output almost in one cell.  The former works once I wrap the formula in a ```SPLIT``` function.  Thanks. Can I ask the purpose of the ```TRIM``` function here?

Comment: TRIM is just a wild guess. that transpose(query(transpose combo joins all columns into one single column adding an empty space after each value so if value is in lets say 3rd column then after the junction there could be 2 empty spaces before the value. so trim removes all excess spaces if/when needed